# Why is my WordPress domain only available without www, and doesn't work with www?

Tags: json, wordpress, dns, ip

Recently, I don't know what happened and the home page of my WordPress website: https://www.tomandlola.com started showing JSON code whenever I try to open it, but the rest of the pages of the website are working totally fine for example: https://www.tomandlola.com/contact-us

So I tried the following but had no success:

1. Deactivated all the plugins at once and the reactivated them gradually
2. Renamed `.htaccess` file from file manager using cpanel, but no success
3. Updated everything (even though rechecking for updates for WordPress version even when it was already on latest version
4. Changed the default theme
5. Rechecked the site's and home page URLs in wp-options in the database from phpMyadmin using cpanel and the URLs are okay i.e: https://www.tomandlola.com for both of them.
6. Tried to add define lines to wp-config.php: `define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://www.tomandlola.com' ); define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.tomandlola.com' );`
7. Tried to add these in functions.php `update_option( 'siteurl', 'http://www.tomandlola.com' ); update_option( 'home', 'http://www.tomandlola.com' );`

But still no success.

This is what my site's homepage is showing

[image: This is what my site's homepage is showing]

One more thing I noticed was that when I tried to access the website using a VPN, it worked fine even with www but without VPN it shows this JSON on the home page with www. I don't know if its some IP address issue or DNS or just some corrupted file somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it to be a DNS propagation issue. Based on the info shared in the question, it looks like the DNS records were not propagated everywhere so for some networks you were not resolving and for some networks(VPN) the domain with www was resolving to the correct IP address.

I can't seem to replicate this at my end currently. Any screenshot or more info will be helpful in identifying the root cause.